# Flutter :FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, speech-to-text

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\jitkumar\Downloads\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

I tried

1. pub get, pub upgrade, pub outdated,flutter doctor
   still no luck

My objective : integrate speech_to_text in my flutter app .

Independently speech_to_text flutter app working fine but i am not able to integrate in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Need more information but I recomend to try
flutter clean